# How to enable Performance logger in HCL Commerce 9.1

Tags: websphere, commerce, hcl

I want to generate trace for performance log but I don't find where enable the trace.

Checking this documentation page https://help.hcltechsw.com/commerce/9.1.0/admin/refs/rlsperflog_dup.html it's mention that we need to use the following string: com.ibm.commerce.performance=fine.

In Logging and Tracing settings we don't have this class path to enable finest log.

I tried to perform some run command in ts-app like:

```
 run set-dynamic-trace-specification com.ibm.commerce.performance=fine
 run set-server-property com.ibm.commerce.performance fine
```

Keep not seeing the trace file in: WAS_profiledir/logs/performanceTrace.json.

Some tip ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Document found:
https://help.hcltechsw.com/commerce/9.1.0/admin/tasks/tlslogging_txn.html

Basically, it's activated by PMT logs.